# Unable Razor post data to api controller via fetch or ajax problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, razor, fetch, razor-pages

I have make a simple razor web project and define as below:
in program.cs
I have add

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

In the controller, I have make this:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class BookController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost("SimplePost")]
    public IActionResult SimplePost([FromForm] BookEntry entry)
    {
        var result = entry;
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

and class is like this:

```
public class BookEntry
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

and then the view page ,

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form id="bookform">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="BookId" class="form-label">Book Id</label>
                            <input type="text" name="BookId" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="BookName" class="form-label">Book Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="BookName" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col position-relative">
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block position-absolute bottom-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="search__btn"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>Post Buton A</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col position-relative">
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block position-absolute bottom-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="search__btn2"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>Post Buton B</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Where I create the two button, so the javascript, I have write below :

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var url = "/api/book/simplepost";
            $("#search__btn").click(function (e) {
                var formData = $("#bookform").serialize();
                fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData,
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                })
                    .then(response => console.log("done"))
            });
             $("#search__btn2").click(function (e) {
                var formData2 = $("#bookform").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    headers:
                    {
                        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    data: formData2,
                    success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                        console.log(`success`);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                       console.log(`error`);
                    }
                }).always(function () {
                    console.log(`always done`);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I click the Post Buton A which is use fetch , it can go to simplepost function, but the entry parameter inside is empty
when I　click the Post Buton B the console page have appear error 400 but I have add header
but it still not working.

Can I know how to fix inside ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass data with query:

```
 $("#search__btn").click(function (e) {
                var formData = $("#bookform").serialize();
                fetch(url+"?"+formData , {
                    method: "POST",
                })
                    .then(response => console.log("done"))
            });
```

action:

```
[HttpPost("SimplePost")]
    public IActionResult SimplePost(BookEntry entry)
    {
        var result = entry;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a ASP.NET Core Web App with which the auto generated code will not map the controllers in your program.cs file. Your code is ok so the only thing you have to do is to add the following line in your program.cs.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();   // this line

app.Run();
```